# Is there a simplified or abridged version of the Mazieres paper describing the Stellar Consensus Protocol?

Tags: consensus, protocol

Is there a simplified document describing the Stellar Consensus Protocol that is more accessible and can be understood by the general public?

I am trying to clarify and simplify the knowledge around the main paper https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmwnhZmEZjc for the purpose of educating the community and potential interested parties.

Comment: The entire purpose of the protocol is that it is to be made open and public. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: thanks for your reply. No, I was asking is there a document that synthesizes and simplifies the Stellar consensus protocol so that it can be accessible and understandable to the general public?

Answer (score 1):

There is https://www.stellar.org/stories/adventures-in-galactic-consensus-chapter-1/, which is a quite nice, as they say, *graphic novel*.

For people who like to think of themselves as very serious, there's this writeup: https://medium.com/a-stellar-journey/on-worldwide-consensus-359e9eb3e949, which also does the job of explaning the protocol basics.

[image: a consensus state]